# ¿Se puede eliminar una cantidad de filas de una tabla a través de un array?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Me explico:

Quiero eliminar una lista de filas de la tabla. Tengo los `id` que voy a eliminar, pero ¿como podría hacerlo?.

Los `id` los tengo, ejemplo:

```
{60,61,62};
```

Y quisiera hacer algo así:

```
DELETE FROM partes WHERE id={60,61,62};
```

Claro si es que se puede.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede usar el operador *incluido* `<@` de postgres

```
delete from partes where array[id] <@ array[61,62,63];
```

Ver el ejemplo en: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dUJ9MGkacTuyWCvrgk21YZ/0

Y el manual en https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html

## = any

También se puede usar `= ANY`:

```
delete from partes where id = any (array[61,62,63]);
```

ver https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dUJ9MGkacTuyWCvrgk21YZ/1

Comment: Gracias hermano, me funciono :D